# Iterate creation of <tr> AND <td> in Thymeleaf

Tags: html-table, iterator, thymeleaf

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
class Tag {
  String text;
  long count;
}
```

And I have it stored in a in a List.  I use this for a classic "tag cloud" construct, where it will show the number of times (count) that a word (text) appears in my database, like so:

```
Billing,10
Balance,6
Account,3
Complaint,1
```

I know I can use th iterators to dynamically place this in a table, like so:

```
<tr>
  <td>Billing</td><td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Balance</td><td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Account</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Complaint</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
```

However, I'm trying to display this data as text and count within a single cell, and then dynamically create a grid structure:

```
(max column width is 3):

<tr>
  <td>Billing - 10</td>
  <td>Balance- 6</td>
  <td>Account- 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Complaint - 1</td>
</tr>
```

How can I use a th iterator to generate both rows and columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use another library to partition the array into groups of 3 (Apache Commons Collections 4.4 has such a method), then you can simply iterate over them.  For example:

```
<table th:with="partitions=${T(org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils).partition(tags, 3)}">
    <tr th:each="partition: ${partitions}">
        <td th:each="tag: ${partition}"><span th:text="${tag.text}" /> - <span th:text="${tag.count}" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```