# Thymeleaf start new row every n elements

Tags: thymeleaf

So I am trying to create a Thymeleaf loop where have a list of n elements. Every fourth (starting at the first) I create a parent element, and each one gets added to that until a new parent is created.

So the idea is

```
for e : elements {
   if index % 4 = 0 {
       create new parent
   }
   add e to parent
}
```

I am trying to implement this in Thymeleaf and cannot get anything working. Here is the closest I think I have gotten (that inner loop causes "IllegalStateException: No index"):

```
             <div th:each="metric, rowStatus : ${metrics}"
                class="row tile_count" th:if="${rowStatus.index % 4} == 0">
                <div th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(rowStatus.index , rowStatus.index +4)}"
                   th:replace="layouts/template.html :: metricCard(name=${metrics[i].name}, value=${metrics[i].value},description=${metrics[i].description}, severity=${metrics[i].severity})"></div>
             </div>
```

The desired html is something in the ball park of:

```
  <div class="row tile_count">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total HR1 Files</span>
      <div class="count">17</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa"></i></i> Same as last Week</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Transactions</span>
      <div class="count green"> 7,353</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>34% </i> From last Week</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Average Processing Time</span>
      <div class="count">43 sec</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>3% </i> From last Week</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Failed Transactions</span>
      <div class="count">0</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="red"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>12% </i> From last Week</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Loaded Transactions</span>
      <div class="count">7,353</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>21% </i> From last Week</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row tile_count">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total HR2 Files</span>
      <div class="count">05</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa"></i></i> Same as last Week</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Transactions</span>
      <div class="count green">5,421</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>10% </i> From last Week</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Average Processing Time</span>
      <div class="count">10 sec</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>3% </i> From last Week</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Failed Transactions</span>
      <div class="count">2</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="red"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>12% </i> From last Week</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      <span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Total Loaded Transactions</span>
      <div class="count">5,419</div>
      <span class="count_bottom"><i class="green"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>10% </i> From last Week</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Something like this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58488991/4126893

Answer (score 0):

You can try `th:remove` like this:

```
<th:block th:each="metric, iterStat : ${metrics}">
<div class="row tile_count" th:remove="${iterStat.index % 4 == 0 ? none : tag}">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count">
      ...
    </div>
</div>
</th:block>
```

Comment: You have a litte mistake in your th:remove syntax. Use   th:remove="${iterStat.index % 4 == 0}? none : tag"     ... you must close the bracket after the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following:

```
 <div class="row pt-5" th:remove="${status.index%4 == 0} ?  none : tag">

    <div class="col">...</div>

 <th:block th:if="${status.index eq 4}" th:utext="'</div>'" />
```

I used this, cause the remove "tag" feature don't delete the closing div from my row.